# Issue building jnativehook

Tags: java, c++, windows, ant, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) just following the steps on the wiki (which seems incomplete) but, when I run `ant all` as instructed I get this error:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\Downloads\jnativehook-master\jnativehook-master`\build.xml:173: Could not load definitions from resource org/jnitask`/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
```

I'm building on Windows 8.1 and I have visual C++ 2015 (I don't want to use Msys2 to do this). I have very low knowledge of ant so any help or clues will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the JNITasks jar to the root of the project.  See the project wiki for full compiling instructions.  https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Compiling

Comment: Oh I totally overlooked that, giving it another shot now.

Comment: Nope that didn't work it still gives me the same error `\jnativehook-master`\build.xml:173: Could not load definitions from resource org/jnitask`/antlib.xml. It could not be found.` I built and added JNItasks.

Comment: The JNITasks.jar file needs to be in the ant classpath.  Putting it in \jnativehook-master\ should work.  If not did you specify a different basedir or build outside the project root?